# Instead Of Delete Trigger with FileStream

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, filestream

Why can't i use an **Instead Of Delete** Trigger on a table that has a varbinary filestream column?

Is there a workaround for it?

I want to update a field when a delete command is performed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may create two tables istead of one:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileStreams](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RowGuid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Data] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_FileStreams] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [RowGuid] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [FilestreamGroup]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [FileStreamId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Files] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Files]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Files_FileStreams] FOREIGN KEY([FileStreamId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[FileStreams] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Files] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Files_FileStreams]
GO
```

Foreign key must be `NO ACTION`. It allows you to create `INSTEAD OF` trigger for table Files

Answer (score 0):

All types of INSTEAD OF triggers are generally not supported with filestream tables - and DELETE is no different in this case. The reason is probably that it would have very complicated semantics in case of UPDATE triggers and out-of-band updates (from .Net or Win32).

If you provide some more details regarding your scenario then perhaps someone will be able to give you a workaround.

Comment: i could fix it with an after delete trigger.
i just made insert there again.
Thx